# Producing a list from a data frame R

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I have a matrix of 2xN, with family name and name, and would like to have a list where the key is the family name and the elements are the people with that last name. I could do this with a for loop and coditionals, but wondering if there is a `reshape` funciton or something that does that directly.

`people<-cbind.data.frame(c(rep("smith",2),rep("miller",2)),c("John","Jane","Alex","Jes"))`

and I want a list where `x[["smith"]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `split()`?

```
split(people[[2]], people[[1]])
$`miller`
[1] Alex Jes 
Levels: Alex Jane Jes John

$smith
[1] John Jane
Levels: Alex Jane Jes John
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for a `list` but for dictionaries in R, may I recommend `hashmap`:

```
people <-cbind.data.frame(c(rep("smith",2),rep("miller",2)),c("John","Jane","Alex","Jes"), stringsAsFactors=F)
H      <- hashmap(people[,1], people[,2])
H
```

> ```
> ## (character) => (character)
> ##    [miller] => [Jes]      
> ##     [smith] => [Jane]
> ```

```
H$values()
```

> ```
> [1] "Jes"  "Jane"
> ```

```
H$keys()
```

> ```
> [1] "miller" "smith"
> ```

It's very efficient, has an incredible toolset, and gives R its missing dictionary functionality and then some!

Value lookup can be performed by passing a vector of lookup keys to either of [[ or $find:

```
H[["smi"]]

H$find("mill")
```

For more info:

https://github.com/nathan-russell/hashmap

Comment: ill definately check it out, thnx for the tip!